# Bloquear a tecla enter dentro do <p:editor>

Tags: java, primefaces

Estou usando java,JPA e PrimeFaces com Wildfly.
Tenho um  do PrimeFaces que quero bloquear quando o usuario apertar a tecla enter não haver nenhuma ação.
Como devo proceder?

Answer (score 2):

No seu inputText coloque na propriedade onkeyPress.
`onkeypress="if(event.keyCode == 13){event.preventDefault(); return false;}"`